# forEach in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach

Can someone please explain to me in-depth how `forEach` works in JavaScript, what it does, and how to use it? All I know is that it is a type of loop that uses functions and arrays. I understand the other loops such as `for`, `while`, `do-while`, and `for-in`, but I just can't understand the `forEach` loop. I have tried other online resources but I am still so lost and don't know what it does and how to "create" one properly, as I don't understand the syntax. Some help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) on the link @Tushar provided should explain everything - it's written for older browsers so should be using simple javascript

Comment: @JaromandaX—since *forEach* was introduced in ES5 it only makes sense to provide a pollyfill compliant with Ed. 3 features. ;-)

Comment: [@Ezama Vaughan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35569115/3434588) I posted an answer with a example on the usage of this function.

Comment: @RobG that was my point - the polyfill uses basic javascript, so does what the question asks for ... an in depth explanation of how forEach works

Answer (score 4):

`Array.prototype.forEach` is a function that loops though all the items in an array, executing a callback function defined as in the first argument. The syntax is shown as below:

```
Array.forEach(function(currentValue, index, array) {}, thisArg);
```

The interior of the function is what code is executed, and the parameters of the callback function are as follows: `currentValue, currentIndex, arrayThatWasCalledOn`

It is generally used to loop through an long array.
The second parameter is a `thisArgument` and whatever value this argument is set to is the corresponding `this` keyword inside the function's scope.

```
Array.forEach(function() {console.log(this.name);}, {name: "value"});
```

*Please note* that once the loop is started, the `break` statement can not be used to exit the loop. This is why a for loop is recommended.

Here is a code example:

```
var fruits = ["lemon", "apple", "orange", "lettuce"];
fruits.forEach(function(currentFruit) {
  if (isFruit(currentFruit) === false) {
    console.log("Error: Item is not a fruit!");
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the optional *thisArg* parameter. ;-)

Comment: [@RobG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569115/foreach-in-javascript/35569289#comment58826498_35569289) *optional*

Comment: Hence "*… **optional** thisArg parameter …*". ;-)

Comment: If you're going to explain "in depth", there are no "optional"

Answer (score 3):

The best way to understand the forEach method is creating it from scratch. The forEach native Javascript function is basically a function that has a loop inside it and will use an iterator function (callback) to execute over each item inside the collection (the collection may be an array or an object).

Ex:

```
  var forEach = function(collection, iterator) {    
    if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        iterator(collection[i], i, collection);
      }
    } else {
      for (var key in collection) {
        iterator(collection[key], key, collection);
      }
    } 
  };
```

Now if you call the forEach function passing the collection and the iterator, it should log each name from the collection:

```
  // This is your collection
  var names = ['John', 'Robert', 'James'];

  // This is the action that you want to perform on each item
  var action = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
  }

  // Now you execute the forEach function passing the collection and the iterator and it should log each name from the collection.
  forEach(names, action); //  Logs -> 'John' 'Robert' 'James'
```

The main difference between the native forEach function and the forEach function we've just created, is that you don't need to pass the collection to it, because Javascript will use the actual object (names) as the collection that you will iterate over.

```
 names.forEach(action); //  Logs -> 'John' 'Robert' 'James'
```

To dive deep in this subject, I would recommend you to read the Functional Programming chapter from [Eloquent Javascript book](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter6.html)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The for each...in statement is deprecated as the part of ECMA-357 (E4X) standard. E4X support has been removed, but for each...in will not be disabled and removed because of backward compatibility considerations. Consider using for...of instead.

Example:

```
var sum = 0;
var obj = {prop1: 5, prop2: 13, prop3: 8}; /* obj array with properties and values */

for each (var item in obj) {
sum += item;
}

console.log(sum);
```

logs "26", which is 5+13+8 here var will iterate over the prop values of the object say, 5,13,8...etc.,,

one important use of these kind of loops in java script is that you dont have to care about the index of arrays or object arrays , whether it is a number or a string , the Loop will iterate ! This is very useful in iterating objects .

Comment: [@user5934157](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35569280/3434588) I believe the OP is looking for the  `Array.prototype.forEach` function.

Comment: Not sure ECMA-357 is relevant here, the *javascript* tag is for EMCA-262 aka ECMAScript.